# how to save history for file in svn using mv?

Tags: svn

trunk1/

svn log show many revisions for each file.

after

svn mv trunk1/ trunk2/

svn log show 1 revision ( create trunk2 ), but I want see ALL revisions for each file in trunk1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `svn copy` followed by a `svn delete` (if you want to completely remove trunk1).  This will retain all the history from trunk1 in the new trunk2.  Only `svn copy` will keep the history of the original location.

The reason this happens is because of some internal workings of `svn move` from the very early days of development of Subversion.  This is something the Subversion development community wants to fix, but it's going to take a lot of work to correct.  This is penciled in for a 2.0 release which could a long time away.